# SDL2 regular jitter when moving a simple texture - even at high fps without vsync

Tags: c++, linux, scroll, sdl-2

I'm trying to make a very simple SDL2 app that just scrolls a texture from an image over the screen.
I need to run it on a pretty old device though:

```
$ inxi -a
CPU: Single Core Intel Atom N270 (-MT-) speed/min/max: 1600/800/1600 MHz
Kernel: 4.9.126-antix.1-486-smp i686 Up: 1m Mem: 94.4/992.7 MiB (9.5%) Storage: 14.92 GiB (32.0% used)
Procs: 154 Shell: bash 4.4.12 inxi: 3.0.36
urve@urve:~
$ inxi -G
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel Mobile 945GSE Express Integrated Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel
           Display: server: X.org 1.19.2 driver: intel tty: 111x45
           Message: Advanced graphics data unavailable in console. Try -G --display

$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           992M         76M        666M         60M        249M        833M
Swap:          2.0G          0B        2.0G
```

It's running Linux Antix:

```
$ uname -a
Linux urve 4.9.126-antix.1-486-smp #1 SMP Mon Sep 10 16:55:08 BST 2018 i686 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: antiX
Description:    antiX 17.2
Release:        17.2
Codename:       stretch
```

Here's output of glxinfo:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 glxinfo
name of display: :0.0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile,
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_multisample,
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile,
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_libglvnd, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap,
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event,
    GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGIS_multisample,
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group,
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGI_swap_control
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile,
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float,
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample,
    GLX_EXT_buffer_age, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile,
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float,
    GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_EXT_import_context,
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating,
    GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer,
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer,
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control,
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer,
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read,
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile,
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample,
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile,
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info,
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer,
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer,
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control,
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer,
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read,
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center (0x8086)
    Device: Mesa DRI Intel(R) 945GME x86/MMX/SSE2 (0x27ae)
    Version: 13.0.6
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 192MB
    Unified memory: yes
    Preferred profile: compat (0x2)
    Max core profile version: 0.0
    Max compat profile version: 2.1
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 2.0
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) 945GME x86/MMX/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 13.0.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1, GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax,
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5,
    GL_APPLE_object_purgeable, GL_APPLE_packed_pixels,
    GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility,
    GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object, GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage,
    GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_debug_output, GL_ARB_depth_texture,
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers, GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex,
    GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location,
    GL_ARB_fragment_program, GL_ARB_fragment_shader,
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, GL_ARB_get_program_binary,
    GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image, GL_ARB_half_float_pixel,
    GL_ARB_internalformat_query, GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata,
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment, GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multi_bind,
    GL_ARB_multisample, GL_ARB_multitexture, GL_ARB_occlusion_query,
    GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_ARB_point_sprite,
    GL_ARB_program_interface_query, GL_ARB_provoking_vertex,
    GL_ARB_robustness, GL_ARB_sampler_objects, GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects,
    GL_ARB_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shading_language_100, GL_ARB_shadow,
    GL_ARB_sync, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, GL_ARB_texture_compression,
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, GL_ARB_texture_env_add,
    GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar,
    GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat,
    GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_texture_rectangle,
    GL_ARB_texture_storage, GL_ARB_transpose_matrix,
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding,
    GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader,
    GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, GL_ATI_draw_buffers,
    GL_ATI_separate_stencil, GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, GL_EXT_abgr,
    GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate,
    GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract,
    GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, GL_EXT_copy_texture,
    GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit,
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters,
    GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil,
    GL_EXT_packed_pixels, GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, GL_EXT_point_parameters,
    GL_EXT_polygon_offset, GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, GL_EXT_rescale_normal,
    GL_EXT_secondary_color, GL_EXT_separate_specular_color,
    GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, GL_EXT_stencil_wrap,
    GL_EXT_subtexture, GL_EXT_texture, GL_EXT_texture3D,
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, GL_EXT_texture_cube_map,
    GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_env_add,
    GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3,
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias,
    GL_EXT_texture_object, GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB,
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, GL_EXT_vertex_array,
    GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip,
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_INGR_blend_func_separate,
    GL_KHR_context_flush_control, GL_KHR_debug, GL_MESA_pack_invert,
    GL_MESA_window_pos, GL_MESA_ycbcr_texture, GL_NV_blend_square,
    GL_NV_light_max_exponent, GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil,
    GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_env_combine4,
    GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_OES_EGL_image, GL_OES_read_format,
    GL_S3_s3tc, GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp,
    GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 13.0.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5,
    GL_APPLE_texture_max_level, GL_EXT_blend_minmax,
    GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer, GL_EXT_draw_buffers,
    GL_EXT_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_EXT_map_buffer_range,
    GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, GL_EXT_read_format_bgra,
    GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects, GL_EXT_texture_border_clamp,
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic,
    GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888, GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV,
    GL_EXT_unpack_subimage, GL_KHR_context_flush_control, GL_KHR_debug,
    GL_NV_draw_buffers, GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments, GL_NV_read_buffer,
    GL_NV_read_depth, GL_NV_read_depth_stencil, GL_NV_read_stencil,
    GL_OES_EGL_image, GL_OES_EGL_sync, GL_OES_depth24, GL_OES_depth_texture,
    GL_OES_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_OES_element_index_uint,
    GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap, GL_OES_get_program_binary, GL_OES_mapbuffer,
    GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil, GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8, GL_OES_stencil8,
    GL_OES_surfaceless_context, GL_OES_texture_3D,
    GL_OES_texture_border_clamp, GL_OES_texture_npot,
    GL_OES_vertex_array_object

12 GLX Visuals
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x020 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x021 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x077 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x078 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x079 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x07b 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07c 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07d 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07e 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07f 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x05e 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None

24 GLXFBConfigs:
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x05f  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x060  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x061  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x062  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x063 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x064 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x065 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x066 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x067  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x068  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x069 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x06b  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06c  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06d  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06e  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06f 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x070 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x071 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x072 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x073  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x074  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x075 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x076 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
```

The problem is, that even though the transition appears to be smooth, there is a constant jitter happening every 3 seconds or so. It looks as if the moving texture jumped back instead of moving forward.

I tried many different methods of smoothing this out. I used delta time based movement, then disabling VSync and limiting the FPS manually, then I found out this question: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/163477/how-can-i-avoid-jittery-motion-in-sdl2

And I applied the same method of capping the framerate as in the answer. Still no help.
Even when using 120FPS (which I'm actually able to achieve), it's better but there is still a visible jitter.

I printed out the difference between last X pos and current during 120FPS:

```
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2.01
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
```

So the results look very OK to me.

With 60FPS, printing the frame time and X position also looks very good:

```
4
Frame time: 0.01667
4
Frame time: 0.01667
4
Frame time: 0.01667
4
Frame time: 0.01667
4
Frame time: 0.01667
4
Frame time: 0.01667
4
Frame time: 0.01667
4
Frame time: 0.01667
4
Frame time: 0.01667
4
Frame time: 0.01667
4
Frame time: 0.01667
4
Frame time: 0.01667
4
Frame time: 0.01667
4.004
Frame time: 0.01668
4
Frame time: 0.01667
4
Frame time: 0.01667
4.003
Frame time: 0.01668
4
Frame time: 0.01667
4
Frame time: 0.01667
4.008
Frame time: 0.0167
4
Frame time: 0.01667
4
Frame time: 0.01667
4.002
Frame time: 0.01667
4
Frame time: 0.01667
4
Frame time: 0.01667
4.003
Frame time: 0.01668
4
Frame time: 0.01667
4
Frame time: 0.01667
4.001
Frame time: 0.01667
4
Frame time: 0.01667
4
Frame time: 0.01667
4
Frame time: 0.01667
```

There are no visible spikes bigger than what you see here, yet the jitter is still there.

The system is running in an forced resolution of 1280x768 @60Hz, but I tried applying other resolutions (either using `gtf` and `cvt` modelines) but it didn't change anything.
I also tried disabling VSync for the entire system using `.drirc` file as mentioned here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics

but it's still the same, although better than when running with vsync and `SDL_RENDERER_PRESENT_VSYNC`.

Surprisingly, setting the `AccelMethod` to `uxa` (instead of default `sna`) actually gets rid of the regular jitter, but the end result is very flickery and hurts the eyes...

I'm running out of ideas.

I checked if anything is hogging the GPU, but it's not even being used at 50%:

```
$ sudo intel_gpu_top
render clock: 166 Mhz  display clock: 200 Mhz
                   render busy:  33%: ██████▋                                render space: 36/131072

                          task  percent busy
                   Bypass FIFO:  32%: ██████▌
              Color calculator:  32%: ██████▌
                    Map filter:  29%: █████▉
                Intermediate Z:  23%: ████▋
                    Windowizer:  22%: ████▌
     Perspective interpolation:   3%: ▋
                  Pixel shader:   3%: ▋
                  Setup engine:   2%: ▌
                    Dispatcher:   2%: ▌
               Strips and fans:   2%: ▌
                 Sampler Cache:   0%:
                        Map L2:   0%:
                     Filtering:   0%:
         Texture decompression:   0%:
            Projection and LOD:   0%:
 Dependent address calculation:   0%:
                 Texture fetch:   0%:
```

Here's a very basic one-file code of the app:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define WIDTH 1280
#define HEIGHT 156

SDL_Renderer* ren = nullptr;
using namespace std;

struct Timer {
    Uint64 previous_ticks{};
    float elapsed_seconds{};

    void tick() {
        const Uint64 current_ticks{SDL_GetPerformanceCounter()};
        const Uint64 delta{ current_ticks - previous_ticks };
        previous_ticks = current_ticks;

        static const Uint64 TICKS_PER_SECOND { SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency() };
        elapsed_seconds = delta / static_cast<float>(TICKS_PER_SECOND);
    }
};

class Object {
    public:
    Object(string fileName, SDL_Renderer* ren) {
        this->ren = ren;
        surf = IMG_Load(fileName.c_str());
        tx = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, surf);
        this->setRect(0, 0, surf->w, surf->h);
        SDL_FreeSurface(surf);
    }

    ~Object() {
        SDL_DestroyTexture(tx);
    }

    SDL_Rect* getDest() { return &dest; };
    SDL_Rect* getSrc() { return &src; };
    SDL_Texture* getTexture() { return tx; };
    void setRect(int x, int y, int w, int h) { 
        //src.x = x;
        //src.y = y;
        src.x = 0;
        src.y = 0;
        src.w = w;
        src.h = h;

        dest.y = y;
        dest.x = x;
        dest.w = w;
        dest.h = h;
        pos_x = static_cast<float>(x);
    }

    void setX(float x) {
        pos_x = x;
        dest.x = roundf(x);
        if(dest.x <= -dest.w) {
            dest.x = WIDTH; 
            pos_x = static_cast<float>(WIDTH); // reset
        }
        cout << setprecision(4) << (last_x - pos_x) << endl;
        last_x = pos_x;
    }

    void setXY(int x, int y) {
        this->setX(static_cast<float>(x));
        dest.y = y;
    }

    void move(float timestep) {
        this->setX(pos_x - (240.0f * (timestep) ));
    }

    void draw() {
        SDL_RenderCopy(this->ren, this->tx, &this->src, &this->dest);
    }

    private:
    float pos_x = 0.0f;
    float last_x = (float)WIDTH;
    SDL_Rect dest;
    SDL_Rect src;
    SDL_Texture *tx = nullptr;
    SDL_Surface *surf = nullptr;
    SDL_Renderer *ren = nullptr;
};

void loop();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Create the SDL window, accelerated renderer without vsync

    SDL_Init(0);
    SDL_Window* win = SDL_CreateWindow("SDLTest", 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0);
    ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(ren, 255, 255, 255, 255);

    loop();
    SDL_Quit();
    return 1;
}



void loop() {
    bool running = true;
    SDL_Rect bg_rect;
    bg_rect.x = 0;
    bg_rect.y = 0;
    bg_rect.w = WIDTH;
    bg_rect.h = HEIGHT;

    const int UPDATE_FREQUENCY { 60 };
    const float CYCLE_TIME { 1.0f / UPDATE_FREQUENCY };

    static Timer timer;
    float accumulated_seconds = 0.0f;

    /*struct timespec tv_sleep;
    tv_sleep.tv_sec = 0;
    tv_sleep.tv_nsec = 10;*/

    Object obj("test.png", ren);
    obj.setXY(WIDTH, 20);
    int iterCount = 0;

    while(running) {

        iterCount++;
        // cap framerate
        timer.tick();
        accumulated_seconds += timer.elapsed_seconds;
        if(accumulated_seconds >= CYCLE_TIME*2.0f || accumulated_seconds <= 0.0 )
            accumulated_seconds = CYCLE_TIME;

        if(std::isgreaterequal(accumulated_seconds, CYCLE_TIME)) {
            SDL_Event e;
            while(SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
                if(e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                    running = false;
                    cout << "QUIT" << endl;
                    return;
                }
            }

            SDL_RenderClear(ren);

            SDL_RenderFillRect(ren, &bg_rect);

            // Draw moving stuff here
            obj.move(accumulated_seconds);
            obj.draw();

            SDL_RenderPresent(ren);

            cout << "Frame time: " << setprecision(4) << accumulated_seconds << endl;

            accumulated_seconds -= CYCLE_TIME;
        }

        /*if(iterCount == 1000) {
            iterCount = 0;
            //sleep(0);
        }*/
    }
}
```

(you just need a `test.png` image in the same directory as SDL loads it to a texture)

I also tried using the FPSManager from `SDL2_framrate.h` but it gave very similar results, if not even worse.

I wanted to apply this method of smoothing the delta: http://frankforce.com/?p=2636

But I couldn't find any implementation of the `GetMonitorRefreshRate()` func, and using SDL's `SDL_GetDisplayMode()` actually returned 0 for every value in the display mode struct. And even if it returned, the `refresh_rate` is an integer, so it won't really help I think.

I'm beginning it's some sort of a problem with the system itself, some missing/corrupted driver or whatever, but I tried installing almost everything I could find without luck.

Here's my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel-flicker-fix.conf` file:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Intel Graphics"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "TearFree" "true"
    Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
EndSection
```

I needed to add the TearFree option, because there was huge tearing on the image when scrolling it.
Here's the gtf modeline I'm using:

```
"1280x768_60.00"  80.00  1280 1344 1480 1680  768 769 772 795  -HSync +Vsync
```

Comment: I don't think your investigation going in right direction - it jitters for me even on adequate desktop hardware. But here are few hints: 1 - vsync is best way to do things, as your client application don't know (and can't know) exact time for present; you almost always slightly miss vertical refresh. 2 - don't use floats for time or position. Now for the second part it could require significant code rewrite, so as workaround you can at least keep float in predictable range where precision is best - e.g. around zero. So, just `timer.tick()` after timer creation would do nicely.

Comment: Hmm that's kinda weird, because you're telling me to not use floats while almost every "solution" I found on the internet tells to use floats for calculating positions to have better precision. With vsync the stutter is still there, and then I cannot really do anything more about the speed. Where is the problem then? Frame times & positions look smooth, but the rendering isn't.

Comment: I suggest thinking about what precision you have with float with data range you have; may be it is enough, may be not. 32bit value can't adapt to anything thrown at it with infinite precision. E.g. float can't tell you difference between `10000` and `10000.0001` - it is the same number, bit to bit, so even on not-so-high numbers you already have noticeably degrading precision. It gets much worse if numbers are higher. Add accumulative imprecision of each calculation and results may be far worse than you expect. But your problem seems to be is much more vsync related.

Comment: Do you have jittering with vsync if you pass constant `CYCLE_TIME` instead of `accumulated_seconds` to your move function, without tearfree option, preferably (not sure what it does, but name is scary)? If it jitters, is *integer* value of difference between old and new `dest.x` fluctuating (e.g. `int o = dest.x`, then recalculate `dest.x`, then compare with `o`)?